# get the old width() with jQuery v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-3

I have a div which is scaled constantly via CSS3, and I want to get the "original" width, not the "scaled/real" width


in jQuery 1.x, 2.x I was able to get it using the width() method, but now in the new version of jQuery (which is v3) I'm getting the "scaled/real" width instead, since now they are using getBoundingClientRect()


so this is my output:

```
$('.myDiv').width(); /* in jQuery 1.x, 2.x  = 380 (I want this) */
$('.myDiv').width(); /* in jQuery 3.0       = 266 */
```

and I tried using the offsetWidth JS method:

```
$('.myDiv')[0].offsetWidth; /* in jQuery 1.x, 2.x  = 380 */
$('.myDiv')[0].offsetWidth; /* in jQuery 3.0       = 380 (not working all the time) */
```

and in jQuery 3.0 it works most of the times, but sometimes I get the "scaled/real" width instead, specially when I refresh the page many times


and as soon as I change jQuery to 1.x or 2.x it works using either **width()** or **offsetWidth**



**Note:** I know I can stick with the 1.x or 2.x versions of jQuery, but I need it to work with v3

Comment: `$('.myDiv')[0].offsetWidth` should always return the same value if you scaled the object the same way, no matter if you use 1.x, 2.x or 3.x, because `.offsetWidth` is a browser functionality and not related to jQuery. You should show how you scale your object.

Comment: Does `.outerWidth()` solve your problem?

Comment: thanks for your replies, I found I was using in other parts of my code the .width() method as well, so I changed all instances of width() to offsetWidth and all seems to be working correctly :D